# Adding a javascript function to an already existing javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, telerik

I wrote a javascript function for Telerik RadTreeView as follows:

```
function CheckedNodeValues() {
    var checkedNodes = $(this).get_checkedNodes();
    for (var n in checkedNodes) {
        checkedNodes[n].get_value();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do `myRadTreeView.CheckedNodeValues()` as opposed to `CheckedNodeValues(myRadTreeView);`

Is there a way to add a function to a class in Javascript?
I hope what I'm asking is clear, ideally, I would like extend the methods available on a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do ..

```
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeView.prototype.CheckedNodeValues = function() {
        var checkedNodes = $(this).get_checkedNodes();
        for (var n in checkedNodes) {
            checkedNodes[n].get_value();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should extend the prototype of your object, like this:

```
myRadTreeView.prototype.CheckedNodeValues = function () {
  // your code here
};
```

You can read more about the prototype concept here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto.shtml or here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely:

```
myRadTreeView.CheckedNodeValues = function () {
      // do totally rad stuff here
};
```

To call it you would use:

```
myRadTreeView.CheckedNodeValues();
```